# angular elements in firefox "this.ngElementStrategy is undefined"

Tags: angular, ngx-build-plus

I'm using `ngx-build-plus` for compile element to js.

*class NgElementImpl*
[image: class NgElementImpl]

Error `ERROR TypeError: can't access property "events", this.ngElementStrategy is undefined` throw at line 512. And the break point is fired. But the point at line 481 isn't.

Offical repo: https://github.com/angular/elements-builds/blob/12.0.x/esm2015/src/create-custom-element.js#L55

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: @LajosArpad As the title show. `ERROR TypeError: can't access property "events", this.ngElementStrategy is undefined`

Comment: @SettingDust were you able to figure it out? I'm having exactly the same issue with Firefox 119.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `createElement` passes HTML element you're creating as `this` inside constructor of `NgElementImpl` instead of instance of `NgElementImpl`. And this `this` doesn't have `NgElementImpl`'s methods or private / protected fields.
The (ugly) solution would be moving all `NgElementImpl` internals outside of the class, into the enclosing function:

1. Download [Angular Elements sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/main/packages/elements) (you can do that via [Download Github Directory](https://download-directory.github.io/) website).
2. Put them into your Angular project.
3. Modify `create-custom-element.ts` by moving implementation of instance methods `get ngElementStrategyImpl` and `subscribeToEvents` outside of the class.

The version below is taken (and rewritten) from Angular 17.0.6 sources.

```ts
/* eslint-disable  */

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument */
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
/* eslint-disable no-prototype-builtins */
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */

import { Injector, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { ComponentNgElementStrategyFactory } from './component-factory-strategy';
import {
  NgElementStrategy,
  NgElementStrategyFactory,
} from './element-strategy';
import {
  getComponentInputs,
  getDefaultAttributeToPropertyInputs,
} from './utils';

/**
 * Prototype for a class constructor based on an Angular component
 * that can be used for custom element registration. Implemented and returned
 * by the {@link createCustomElement createCustomElement() function}.
 *
 * @see [Angular Elements Overview](guide/elements "Turning Angular components into custom elements")
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export interface NgElementConstructor<P> {
  /**
   * An array of observed attribute names for the custom element,
   * derived by transforming input property names from the source component.
   */
  readonly observedAttributes: string[];

  /**
   * Initializes a constructor instance.
   * @param injector If provided, overrides the configured injector.
   */
  new (injector?: Injector): NgElement & WithProperties<P>;
}

/**
 * Implements the functionality needed for a custom element.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export abstract class NgElement extends HTMLElement {
  /**
   * The strategy that controls how a component is transformed in a custom element.
   */
  protected abstract getngElementStrategy(): NgElementStrategy;
  /**
   * A subscription to change, connect, and disconnect events in the custom element.
   */
  protected ngElementEventsSubscription: Subscription | null = null;

  /**
   * Prototype for a handler that responds to a change in an observed attribute.
   * @param attrName The name of the attribute that has changed.
   * @param oldValue The previous value of the attribute.
   * @param newValue The new value of the attribute.
   * @param namespace The namespace in which the attribute is defined.
   * @returns Nothing.
   */
  abstract attributeChangedCallback(
    attrName: string,
    oldValue: string | null,
    newValue: string,
    namespace?: string
  ): void;
  /**
   * Prototype for a handler that responds to the insertion of the custom element in the DOM.
   * @returns Nothing.
   */
  abstract connectedCallback(): void;
  /**
   * Prototype for a handler that responds to the deletion of the custom element from the DOM.
   * @returns Nothing.
   */
  abstract disconnectedCallback(): void;
}

/**
 * Additional type information that can be added to the NgElement class,
 * for properties that are added based
 * on the inputs and methods of the underlying component.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export type WithProperties<P> = {
  [property in keyof P]: P[property];
};

/**
 * A configuration that initializes an NgElementConstructor with the
 * dependencies and strategy it needs to transform a component into
 * a custom element class.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export interface NgElementConfig {
  /**
   * The injector to use for retrieving the component's factory.
   */
  injector: Injector;
  /**
   * An optional custom strategy factory to use instead of the default.
   * The strategy controls how the transformation is performed.
   */
  strategyFactory?: NgElementStrategyFactory;
}

/**
 *  @description Creates a custom element class based on an Angular component.
 *
 * Builds a class that encapsulates the functionality of the provided component and
 * uses the configuration information to provide more context to the class.
 * Takes the component factory's inputs and outputs to convert them to the proper
 * custom element API and add hooks to input changes.
 *
 * The configuration's injector is the initial injector set on the class,
 * and used by default for each created instance.This behavior can be overridden with the
 * static property to affect all newly created instances, or as a constructor argument for
 * one-off creations.
 *
 * @see [Angular Elements Overview](guide/elements "Turning Angular components into custom elements")
 *
 * @param component The component to transform.
 * @param config A configuration that provides initialization information to the created class.
 * @returns The custom-element construction class, which can be registered with
 * a browser's `CustomElementRegistry`.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export function createCustomElement<P>(
  component: Type<any>,
  config: NgElementConfig
): NgElementConstructor<P> {
  const inputs = getComponentInputs(component, config.injector);

  const strategyFactory =
    config.strategyFactory ||
    new ComponentNgElementStrategyFactory(component, config.injector);

  const attributeToPropertyInputs = getDefaultAttributeToPropertyInputs(inputs);
  let _ngElementStrategy: NgElementStrategy | undefined;

  function getngElementStrategyImpl(
    that: NgElement,
    injector?: Injector
  ): NgElementStrategy {
    // TODO(andrewseguin): Add e2e tests that cover cases where the constructor isn't called. For
    // now this is tested using a Google internal test suite.
    if (!_ngElementStrategy) {
      const strategy = (_ngElementStrategy = strategyFactory.create(
        injector || config.injector
      ));

      // Re-apply pre-existing input values (set as properties on the element) through the
      // strategy.
      inputs.forEach(({ propName, transform }) => {
        if (!that.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
          // No pre-existing value for `propName`.
          return;
        }

        // Delete the property from the instance and re-apply it through the strategy.
        const value = (that as any)[propName];
        delete (that as any)[propName];
        strategy.setInputValue(propName, value, transform);
      });
    }

    return _ngElementStrategy!;
  }
  let ngElementEventsSubscription: Subscription | null = null;
  function subscribeToEvents(): void {
    if (!instance) {
      return;
    }
    // Listen for events from the strategy and dispatch them as custom events.
    ngElementEventsSubscription = getngElementStrategyImpl(
      instance,
      instance.injector
    ).events.subscribe(e => {
      const customEvent = new CustomEvent(e.name, { detail: e.value });
      instance!.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
    });
  }
  let instance: NgElementImpl | undefined;
  class NgElementImpl extends NgElement {
    // Work around a bug in closure typed optimizations(b/79557487) where it is not honoring static
    // field externs. So using quoted access to explicitly prevent renaming.
    static readonly ['observedAttributes'] = Object.keys(
      attributeToPropertyInputs
    );

    protected override getngElementStrategy(): NgElementStrategy {
      if (!instance) {
        throw new Error('Illegal state');
      }
      return getngElementStrategyImpl(instance, instance.injector);
    }

    // private _ngElementStrategy?: NgElementStrategy;

    constructor(public readonly injector?: Injector) {
      super();
      instance = this;
    }

    override attributeChangedCallback(
      attrName: string,
      oldValue: string | null,
      newValue: string,
      namespace?: string
    ): void {
      if (!instance) {
        throw new Error('Illegal state');
      }
      const [propName, transform] = attributeToPropertyInputs[attrName]!;
      getngElementStrategyImpl(instance, instance.injector).setInputValue(
        propName,
        newValue,
        transform
      );
    }

    override connectedCallback(): void {
      // For historical reasons, some strategies may not have initialized the `events` property
      // until after `connect()` is run. Subscribe to `events` if it is available before running
      // `connect()` (in order to capture events emitted during initialization), otherwise subscribe
      // afterwards.
      //
      // TODO: Consider deprecating/removing the post-connect subscription in a future major version
      //       (e.g. v11).

      let subscribedToEvents = false;
      if (!instance) {
        return;
      }

      if (getngElementStrategyImpl(instance, instance.injector).events) {
        // `events` are already available: Subscribe to it asap.
        subscribeToEvents();
        subscribedToEvents = true;
      }

      getngElementStrategyImpl(instance, instance.injector).connect(instance);

      if (!subscribedToEvents) {
        // `events` were not initialized before running `connect()`: Subscribe to them now.
        // The events emitted during the component initialization have been missed, but at least
        // future events will be captured.
        subscribeToEvents();
      }
    }

    override disconnectedCallback(): void {
      if (!instance) {
        return;
      }
      // Not using `this.ngElementStrategy` to avoid unnecessarily creating the `NgElementStrategy`.
      if (_ngElementStrategy) {
        _ngElementStrategy.disconnect();
      }

      if (ngElementEventsSubscription) {
        ngElementEventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
        ngElementEventsSubscription = null;
      }
    }
  }

  // Add getters and setters to the prototype for each property input.
  inputs.forEach(({ propName, transform }) => {
    Object.defineProperty(NgElementImpl.prototype, propName, {
      get(): any {
        if (!instance) {
          return;
        }
        return getngElementStrategyImpl(
          instance,
          instance.injector
        ).getInputValue(propName);
      },
      set(newValue: any): void {
        if (!instance) {
          return;
        }
        getngElementStrategyImpl(instance, instance.injector).setInputValue(
          propName,
          newValue,
          transform
        );
      },
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
    });
  });

  return NgElementImpl as any as NgElementConstructor<P>;
}
```

4. Use `createCustomElement` from this modified `create-custom-element.ts` instead of importing it from Angular Elements.
5. Remove `version.ts` from copy-pasted Angular Elements sources.

You might need to either add `"noImplicitAny": false,` to your `tsconfig.app.json`, or to further adjust the source code to avoid compilation errors. Also, consider adding `/* eslint-disable */` to the top of each copy-pasted Angular Elements files to avoid linter errors.

The [related bug in Angular repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32122) was marked as fixed, but it still strikes back at you in Firefox 120 as of 2023-12-11.